# Django {% blocktrans %}: How to handle pluralization inside a for loop?

Tags: python, django, templates, pluralize

I have the following loop in my Django template:

```
{% for item in state.list %}

    <div> HTML (CUSTOMERS BY STATE) </div>

    <!-- print sum of customers at bottom of list -->
    {% if forloop.last %}
        <h4>{{ forloop.counter }} Valued Customers</h4>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, if I end up with only one customer, I'd like to print singular "Valued Customer"

According to Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std%3atemplatetag-blocktrans), one should use `blocktrans`. Tried the following, a few flavors of nesting:

```
    {% blocktrans count %}
        {% if forloop.last %}
            <h4>
                {{ forloop.counter }}
                &nbsp;Valued Customer
                {% plural %}
                &nbsp;Valued Customers
            </h4>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblocktrans %}
```

Keep getting **TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'blocktrans', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'**

Is there no way to combine with another loop? Any ideas how to solve? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, you forgot to [load translation tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code). Add following line at the top of your template:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

After you fix that, note that for a `blocktrans` tag after `count` a variable, whose value will serve for plural detection, should be specified, so you probably need something like

```
{% blocktrans count count=forloop.counter %}
```

Comment: Had no idea about having to load the tags. Needing to provide a value for count makes total sense. I had to rearrange per below, but works great now -- thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working code, thanks to alko:

```
{% load i18n %}

<!-- ... -->

{% if forloop.last %}
    <h4>
        {{ forloop.counter }}
        {% blocktrans count count=forloop.counter %}
             Valued Customer
        {% plural %}
             Valued Customers
        {% endblocktrans %} 
    </h4>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To pluralize use this:

```
Customer{{ forloop.counter|pluralize }}
```

Comment: Probably more what I needed for this simple case of pluralization :)

Comment: Be aware that this one is not translatable. You probably want to use the blocktrans/plural method.